# Any GUI lib out there that can portably handle *not* being in the main thread?

Tags: c++, c, user-interface, tcl, tk-toolkit

What it says on the tin.

Qt 5.x does it fine on Windows (despite the console warning message), but chokes on repainting in Linux, and apparently anything based on Cocoa (which I've never used) strangles itself if you put the GUI event loop outside of the main thread.

So, is there anything out there that can handle not-being-created/not-having-its-event-loop-running in the main thread reliably across Windows and Linux (and maybe Mac, but that seems like a longshot)?

The background here is that I have a DLL/SO that I want to use via tclsh, and I want that DLL/SO to provide a GUI. I *can* mess with the SWIG generated wrappers to get the main interpreter and get something to run from there, but messing with that seems like a major hassle. I've experimented a bit with Tk, but even after calling Tk_Init, Tk_MainWindow returns `NULL` on the interpreter in the created thread (the interpreter was also created in that thread). Code provision on demand.

EDIT: code. This is all ran in a separate thread created after DLL/SO load via `load <libname>.so` in `tclsh`.

```
Tcl_Interp* interp = Tcl_CreateInterp();
Tcl_AppInit(interp); // added on suggestion - all results the same so far
Tk_Init(interp);
/* GDB reveals 'interp->resultDontUse' to be blank here.
  Return value of the above statement is 1 (TCL_ERROR) */
Tk_Window main_window = Tk_MainWindow(interp);
// main_window is NULL here, and thus the following line fails miserably
Tk_Window canvas = Tk_CreateWindow(interp, main_window, "gfx", NULL);
while(true) {
    { ... }
    Tcl_DoOneEvent(TCL_DONT_WAIT);
}
Tcl_DeleteInterp(interp);
```

N.B. I'm still okay with switching libs. If there's a lib out there for which the original question works and the above can't be made to work, I'd switch.

**UPDATE**

Tcl/Tk appears to be handling being in the non-main thread just fine. At the very least, better than Qt. Thanks!

Comment: If `Tk_MainWindow` is returning NULL, it should also be leaving an error message. What's in `interp->result` after `Tk_MainWindow` returns? Also, from which thread are you calling `Tk_MainWindow`?

Comment: @ElchononEdelson Added code and results of intermediate results in comments. The added code is all executed in a separate thread created after DLL/SO load.

Comment: Hmm. After `Tk_Init()` returns 1, what does `Tcl_GetObjResult()` tell you?

Comment: Note: `interp->result` is deprecated (and not longer used internally).

Comment: I suggest calling `Tcl_Init(interp)` too.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Added the init - any other initialization things I might be missing...?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn How would I use Tcl_GetObjResult here...? (I'll dive into the docs for now but please answer anyway because I'm lost on this -.-')

EDIT: OKAY NEVERMIND THERE'S AN ERROR THERE. Version conflict. Will fix that, try again, and get back.

Comment: And Tcl/Tk handles being in the non-main thread *beautifully*. Unlike Qt. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Right, since this question was answered via comments, I'm moving the answer into answerhood.</sub>

Yes, the Tk GUI library can do just fine being not in the main thread. The problem you were having was that your initialization was failing (due to a version mismatch, by your words), and since you weren't properly checking the result, you weren't noticing the error.